# FormulaEvaluator POI evaluating with more than 2 decimals

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I'm using FormulaEvaluator from Apache POI to evaluate 2 cells sum :

10.00 (Cell 1) + 0.80 (Cell 2) = 10.80

This sum in Excel shows 10.80 which is true, but with POI's FormulaEvaluator the result is 10.799999998!

```
CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
```

This is not working.

Why is this wrong with Apache POI and how can I get the formula well evaluated? I'm not looking to round the result because I'm trying to validate every cell on that Excel's two decimals only. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the source cells don't contain a precision more important than two decimal?

Comment: Are you aware of how Floating Point maths works? If not, what happens after you've read the wikipedia article or similar tutorial?

Comment: Yes, those cells are two decimals precision

Comment: I am aware how floating point works, but please explain me what happens when the article tutorial is read. Sarcasm  is not ver helpfull.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. If `A1` contains the value 10 and `A2` contains the value 0.8 and `A3` contains the formula `=A1+A2`, then `CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);` gets a cell value of 10.8, if  `cell` is `A3`. So if you really wants help, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which makes your problem reproducible.